# Exporting overloaded functions with fpc

Tags: delphi, dll, overloading, fpc

I need to create a dll within fpc (delphi-mode). It works fine - but for some reasons, I want to do something (in a unit) like

```
function doSomeThing(a:type1):type2;stdcall;
function doSomeThing(a:type3):type4;stdcall;
```

and in the library (for building the dll using the unit above)

```
exports
    doSomeThing(a:type1) name 'doSomeThingTYPE1',
    doSomeThing(a:type3) name 'doSomeThingTYPE3';
```

The syntax is self explanatory and is told in [How to export Overload functions from DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583167/how-to-export-overload-functions-from-dll) . But it seems to be unavailable in fpc (version 2.6.0-9 [2013/04/14] for x86_64). Is there a chance to do something like that - or do I have to rename the functions within my source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David consulted me in another thread, I devised something that compiles, but don't know if it works.

It is based on exporting the function using a defined linker level identifier, and then declaring an external function reimporting it with different Pascal names. Note that bla and bla2 doesn't even have to be in the same unit as dosomething variants.

```
library testdll; 

{$mode delphi}
type 
   type1=integer;
   type3=char;
   type2=smallint;
   type4=widechar;

function doSomeThing(a:type1):type2;stdcall; overload; [public, alias:'bla'];
begin
  result:=a+1;
end;

function doSomeThing(a:type3):type4;stdcall; overload; [public, alias:'bla2'];
begin
  result:=widechar(ord(a)+1000);
end;

procedure bla; external name 'bla';
procedure bla2; external name 'bla2';
exports
    bla name 'doSomeThingTYPE1',
    bla2 name 'doSomeThingTYPE3';

end.
```

Comment: Hi Marco, this is a quite cool workaround. I'll wait a bit - and if no real answer comes, I'll accept it as the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if it works (you can successfully call the functions)

Answer (score 2):

The question that you link to discusses Delphi. The syntax that Delphi supports, that allows you to export overloaded functions, is not supported by FPC.

To the best of my knowledge, overloaded functions are not exportable. Although, I could easily be wrong on that score. Perhaps there is a way, as Marco proposes in his answer.

Comment: Hi David, this matches my experiences - but it this documented anywhere - or will that be changed in the near future?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not an expert of fpc (to put it mildly).